# List RHEL EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat

We have a mix of Amazon and RHEL EC2 Linux instances. I'm going to purchase instance reservations, but I need to know how many reservations of each to buy. I don't know how to do that short of SSHing into each instance and looking around. I know the RHEL instances are being billed separately by looking at the account activity, so Amazon must have the info; I just don't know where to find it.

I tried the ec2-describe-instances command, which says that it lists the product codes, (which I'm hoping I could parse into Amazon or RHEL) but I don't see them. It lists the key name, the launch index, then the instance type. The documentation suggests that the product codes would be listed before the instance type, but I don't see them.

Answer (score 0):

Just feed the AMI IDs of your instances to [`ec2-describe-images`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeImages.html). For example:

```
ec2-describe-images ami-35792c5c ami-a25415cb
```

Comment: Yes, but which of the fields is the product code, and how do I interpret the product code?

Comment: Why are you asking about the product codes? They aren't even relevant to your question!

Comment: What should I be looking at?